# filter Graphql result by a Date variable

Tags: javascript, database, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm using `graphql` with `gatsby` to get data from my DataBase. Below is my query:

```
export const querymk = graphql`
  query HomePageQuery {
  allMongodbAppsOneapps (
      filter : { my_time: { eq : "2019-08-21T12:35:56.863Z" }}
  )  {
    nodes {
      id
      my_time(formatString: "DD MMMM YYYY")
      text {
        title
        developer
        icon
      }
    }
  }
}
`
```

this is working fine.. but i need to replace my filter : `eq : "2019-08-21T12:35:56.863Z"` by a variable `date` ( `eq : $mydate`).. i don't know where to start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables can be passed by providing them in the named query.

Check out the following example:

```
export const querymk = graphql`
  query HomePageQuery($dateFormat : String!) {
  allMongodbAppsOneapps (
      filter : { my_time: { eq: $dateFormat }}
  )  {
    nodes {
      id
      my_time(formatString: "DD MMMM YYYY")
      text {
        title
        developer
        icon
      }
    }
  }
}
`
```

To pass a variable to a query it has to be passed as context when creating the page:

```
createPage({
    ...page,
    context: {
      ...page.context,
      dateFormat: `2019-08-21T12:35:56.863Z`,
    },
  })
```

This only works for compile time queries, this is a restriction from gatsby:

> Gatsby uses GraphQL at build-time and not for live sites. This is unique, and it means you don’t need to run additional services (e.g. a database and Node.js service) to use GraphQL for production websites.

source: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/querying-with-graphql/#how-do-graphql-and-gatsby-work-together

Related docs: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/#creating-pages-in-gatsby-nodejs

Comment: how can i pass $dateFormat to my query?

Comment: I updated the answer, can you show the code where you use the GraphQL query? @FatimaTT

Comment: i received this error: `Error: It appears like Gatsby is misconfigured. Gatsby related `graphql` calls are supposed to only be evaluated at compile time, and then compiled away,. Unfortunately, something went wrong and the query was left in the compiled code.`

Comment: so it means i can only use the fixed value in Gatsby node config file?

Comment: Yes, graphql is only for compile time, read more about it here: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/querying-with-graphql/#how-do-graphql-and-gatsby-work-together @FatimaTT